# Android Test - Run specific test case for each devices sequentialy

Tags: integration-testing, appium, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I have built Android application and Server as below:

> Users connect to server to make some actions, server will hold
>   action's information. 
>  Operators connect to server to view user's
>   actions.

And I want to test sequentially this case below with two emulators/two devices:

 Emulator 1: User logins to Server and makes action A

 Emulator 2: Operator logins to Server and view action A

I think I will make 2 test cases to verify my application works successfully

TestCase #1: User logins to Server and makes action A

TestCase #2: Operator logins to Server and view action A

I want to use uiautomator and Appium to run test suite.

For example, Device#1 executes TestCase#1, after that Device#2 executes TestCase#2.

Could appium/uiautomator execute test with my conditions above? 

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your scenarios are achievable with Appium. But to achieve this, make sure you take the following points to consideration:

- You need to start 2 Appium servers on separate ports, separate bootstrap ports and separate call back ports.

E.g.:

```
appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723 -cp 1234 -bp 2345
```

- You create 2 Android drivers in your test, each for each emulator.

This should be good for you to run your tests sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

you can take help of testNG framework to achieve this.
In testng.xml file create a test suite with two test tags that run two test cases you mentioned above and pass a parameter from each test tag to identify which one is client and which one is server and using this info code accordingly in @BeforeTest and @AfterTest and then create two @Test methods and using testNG tags @depends you can link these two tests and write the code accordingly